# How to retrieve and display data in a table view from an array containing dictionaries?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I am attempting to retrieve data from Firebase and display it in a table view. The problem is that the values are not showing in the table view. 
As of right now, I am iterating through the data I have in firebase and storing each dictionary in an array. Then with that array of dictionaries, I try to set a label in a table view cell equal to a value in the dictionary.

Here is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let arrayWithFirbaseInfo : Array<Dictionary<String, Any>> = findCordinateFolder()
    print(arrayWithFirbaseInfo)

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customTableCell", for: indexPath) as! NearbyTableViewCell

    cell.distanceLabel.text = arrayWithFirbaseInfo.filter({$0["favorite drink"] != nil}).map({$0["favorite drink"]!}) as? String

   return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}



func findCordinateFolder() ->  Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>{
    var firebaseArray = Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>()

    ref = Database.database().reference()

    var currentLocation: CLLocation!
    currentLocation = locManager.location

    GeocodeFunction().geocode(latitude: currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: currentLocation.coordinate.longitude, completion: { placemark, error in
        if let error = error as? CLError {
            print("CLError:", error)
            return
        } else if let placemark = placemark?.first {
            // you should always update your UI in the main thread
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                //  update UI here

                //                    let city = placemark.locality ?? "unknown"

                let state = placemark.administrativeArea ?? "unknown"

                let storageRef = self.ref.child("drinkingFountains").child(state)
                storageRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                    for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                        var dict = child.value as? [String : Any] ?? [:]
                        let coordinateDistanceFrom = CLLocation(latitude: dict["lat"] as! Double, longitude: dict["long"] as! Double)
                        let distanceInMeters = currentLocation.distance(from: coordinateDistanceFrom)
                        dict["distanceFromCurrentLocation"] = String(distanceInMeters)

                        firebaseArray.append(dict)


                    }

                })
            }
        }
    })
    return firebaseArray
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the code in cell for row at index path as below:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let arrayWithFirbaseInfo : Array<Dictionary<String, Any>> = findCordinateFolder()
   print(arrayWithFirbaseInfo)

   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customTableCell", for: indexPath) as! NearbyTableViewCell
   let isIndexValid = arrayWithFirbaseInfo.indices.contains(indexPath.row)
   if isIndexValid {
   cell.distanceLabel.text = arrayWithFirbaseInfo[indexPath.row]["favorite drink"] as? String
   }
   return cell 
}
```

Try to move the arrayWithFirbaseInfo to the viewdidload instead of declaring it inside the cell for row method. 
Also you should modify the number of rows function with the array.count as

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return arrayWithFirbaseInfo.count
}
```

Comment: When I move the 'let arrayWithFirbaseInfo : Array<Dictionary<String, Any>> = findCordinateFolder()' into the viewDidLoad I get errors in the cellForRowAt function. @Joshua

Comment: move the let arrayWithFirbaseInfo : Array<Dictionary<String, Any>> to the outside scope and instead of let use var. and then inside viewdidload just to arrayWithFirbaseInfo = findCordinateFolder(). Let me know how it goes.

Comment: var arrayWithFirbaseInfo = [[String:Any]]() this is how I will do

Comment: I set  `var arrayWithFirbaseInfo = Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>()` on the outside scope and then I set `arrayWithFirbaseInfo = findCordinateFolder()` in the viewDidLoad. I also added a print statement to see the values in the array but it seems that the array is empty since its printing [ ]

Comment: i also tried doing var arrayWithFirbaseInfo = [[String:Any]]() but still didnt work

Comment: simply do tableview.reload after u set the array.

Comment: also after setting the array like arrayWithFirbaseInfo = findCordinateFolder()
do a print statement to see if the array is empty or not

Comment: I added a print statement and the output was empty: [ ]. So I changed my findCordinateFolder() and instead of returning the array and calling it in `viewDidLoad with arrayWithFirbaseInfo = findCordinateFolder()` I am appending the dict in the for loop directly to the global array like this:                                         `self.arrayWithFirbaseInfo.append(dict)`. I also called the function in viewDidLoad and added the line `tableView.reloadData()` to the cellForRowAt function. Yet for some reason the cells are blank.

Comment: are u sure the array is not nil before returning, can u print out the array inside the function to make sure array is not empty. you should noe add reload inside cellForRow function that is wrong

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. The code is now functional!